# Intuition for orientation of tri-vectors in geometric algebra

Tags: geometry, vectors, geometric-algebras

I am learning geometric algebra from the MacDonald textbook and it states that the outer product is associative. Letting $\bf{u}$, $\bf{v}$, and $\bf{w}$ be vectors

$$\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v} \wedge \bf{w}= (\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v}) \wedge \bf{w} =\bf{u} \wedge (\bf{v} \wedge \bf{w}).$$

But the book describes the volume created by 
$(\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v}) \wedge \bf{w}$
has orientation given by $\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v}$, while $\bf{u} \wedge (\bf{v} \wedge \bf{w})$ has orientation given by $\bf{v} \wedge \bf{w}$.

I understand that they are the same volume, but what I'm not getting is the understanding of what the orientation of an oriented volume actually is. Is it saying that $\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v}$ and $\bf{v} \wedge \bf{w}$ have the same orientation even though they are not in parallel planes?

Also, any tips on gaining an overall intuition of orientation of higher dimensional objects would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

An updated version of the section in question has been posted here:

http://www.faculty.luther.edu/~macdonal/laga/LAGA%20Section%205.2.pdf

This rewritten section provides a different explanation than above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with MacDonalds book, but this does not sound right to me; the orientation of a volume element $u\wedge v \wedge w$ should depend upon all three factors and not just two of them.

The outer product is otherwise known as the wedge or exterior product. It is a signed version of the tensor product, hence used when orientation matters.

They generalise vectors; recall that vectors have direction and magnitude. The outer product of two vectors give a '2d vector', an orientated area element, this ought to be thought of as the generalisation of direction to higher dimensions, where instead of working in higher dimensions per se - for example in a 10d or 20d space - we are working with higher dimensional vectors; the generalisation of magnitude then is the area.

The generalisation to 3d vectors is then obvious: the outer product of three vectors gives an orientated volume element and the magnitude is now the volume.

This explains why the outer product of a vector by itself always vanishes; this is because the area element degenerates into a line element, and hence it's area vanishes; likewise its volume.

The arithmetic of the outer product shows that a generalisation of the triangle law still holds, so long as the two area elements in question have an edge of common magnitude; it's also important to note that the multi-linearity of the outer product means that we can rescale the area element in such a way that it's total area does not change; for example we can magnify one edge by a scale factor $k$ so long as we reduce the other side by $k$ - this has no parallel in the arithmetic of vectors.

Answer (score 2):

The orientation of $\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v}$ is given by the orientation of $\bf{u}$ on the *boundary* of $\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v}$. See Fig. 5.5 in my book and the accompanying text.

Similarly, the orientation of $\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v} \wedge \bf{w}$ is given by the orientation of $\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v}$ (or $\bf{v} \wedge \bf{w}$ or $\bf{w} \wedge \bf{u}$) on the *boundary* of $\bf{u} \wedge \bf{v} \wedge \bf{w}$. All are clockwise.

Perhaps this is a better explanation than in my book.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Note 3 on pg 75 of your book says that orientation of areas in a plane can only be compared, but can you compare them if they aren't in the same plane?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing: The orientation aspects of Section 5.2 and my reply yesterday are wrongheaded. I am rewriting the section and will post it as a pdf on the book's website within a few days. My apologies.

Comment: Orientations of areas not in parallel planes cannot be compared.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep an eye out for the update. Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that the wedge product is not associative? Or am I misreading that?

Comment: The outer product is definitely associative. My explanation of this fact was incorrect. There is no problem proceeding with the text if you accept the associativity.

Comment: I have posted an improved version of Section 5.2 at http://www.faculty.luther.edu/~macdonal/laga/LAGA%20Section%205.2.pdf